# How to use service name instead of External IP/domain name for a service endpoint url in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed application on my kubernetes cluster and I have exposed the service as well. As I am using AWS cloud, I got external IP (domain name) for particular service to access it.

While exposing the service I have mentioned the name to the service.
Now I want to use service name, instead of external IP.

```
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)
Service1         LoadBalancer   1.x.x.x          test1.com      1000:3000/TCP
Service2         LoadBalancer   2.x.x.x          test2.com      2000:4000/TCP
```

Here,
now I am using `test1.com:1000` to access my application.
But I want to use `Service1:1000` to access my application. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What problem are you encountering?  From within the cluster, you should be able to just use `service1.default.svc.cluster.local` as a host name.

Comment: Where do you yo use? inside or outside the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 services behind ELB, and you can call you services only by `test1.com:1000` from outside. If you call the service from inside the cluster, you can use `service1:3000`  as an endpoint because it is inside the cluster where [kube-dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) works, which resolves all these names inside the cluster.